# Update table for SQLite causes "LIKE or GLOB pattern too complex (code 1)" error

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap

I'm trying to save bitmap string in SQLite database, but instead I get the following error when I tried updating my database: `LIKE or GLOB pattern too complex (code 1)`

I've gotten the bitmap from my ImageView `cropImageView` and converted it into bitmap > string as follows:

```
 UserDatabase db = new UserDatabase(getApplicationContext());
 HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) cropImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
 String stringBitmap = bitMapToString(bitmap);
 db.updateUsers(user.get("image"), user.get("email"), user.get("username"), stringBitmap);
```

Here is my code for UserDatabase:

```
    public class UserDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login_database";
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login_table";

    // Column items
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";

    public UserDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT " + ");";

       db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    // This method stores user details in database.
    public void addUser(String image, String email, String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, image); // Image
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, username); // Username

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    // This method updates user information.
    public void updateUsers(String image, String email, String username, String latest_image) {
        String selection = KEY_IMAGE + " LIKE ? AND " + KEY_EMAIL + " LIKE ? AND " + KEY_USERNAME + " LIKE ? ";
        String[] args = { image, email, username };

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, latest_image);

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_LOGIN, values, selection, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_like_pattern_length) says:

> The length of the LIKE or GLOB pattern is limited to SQLITE_MAX_LIKE_PATTERN_LENGTH bytes. The default value of this limit is 50000.

Anyway, there should be no need to search for user records by the image contents. Just use the primary key.